# strange behavior of cmake ctest for bigger CTEST_PARALLEL_LEVEL

Tags: makefile, cmake, googletest, ctest

I am new to the SO.
I have a simple unit test code where I am doing following operations :

1. calculating square root of the number using `mysqrt` library .
2. Using the output of square root, adding this result with same number and display the result.

When I am running the code with `CTEST_PARALLEL_LEVEL = 1` my all test cases are passing.

But when I do `CTEST_PARALLEL_LEVEL = 8` then my test cases are failing some time for some input which is not fixed in every run.

99% the ALL results are passing but 1% its failing.

**Error:**

```
mysqrt.o: file not recognized: File truncated
```

I have deleted the object file explicitly by using rm *.o ,But still this error is coming after few runs .

I am not sure why this error is coming with `CTEST_PARALLEL_LEVEL = 8`

I am attaching my `CMakeList` only as some of Stack Overflow expert can understand the issue by checking these 3 `CMakeLists.txt` files.

NOTE: As per the Stack overflow guidelines I am not attaching my source code of **sqrt** and **addition** function to avoid the bigger length of the question .

My folder structure:

```
SAMPLE_TEST

├── CMakeLists.txt
├── MathFunctions
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── MathFunctions.h
│   └── mysqrt.cpp
└── unit_test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── step2
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── execute.cpp
        └── tutorial.cpp
```

**SAMPLE_TEST**

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(Tutorial)
ENABLE_TESTING()    
add_subdirectory(MathFunctions)
add_subdirectory(unit_test)
```

**MathFunctions folder**

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(MathFunctions mysqrt.cpp)
set(REF_FILES mysqrt.cpp)
add_definitions(-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11)
add_custom_target(build_reference_library
      DEPENDS sqrtlib
      COMMENT "Generating sqrtlib")
ADD_LIBRARY(sqrtlib OBJECT ${REF_FILES})
```

**unit_test folder**

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(REF_MATHLIB_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../MathFunctions)

macro(GENERATION file input)
  set(ip_generator ctest_input_${input})

  add_executable(${ip_generator}
    ${file}
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:sqrtlib>
    )

  target_compile_options(${ip_generator} PUBLIC
    -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11 
    -DCTEST_INPUT=${input})


  target_link_libraries(${ip_generator} PUBLIC
    dl pthread
    )

  target_include_directories(${ip_generator} PUBLIC
    ${REF_MATHLIB_DIR}
    )

  set(INPUT_FILE0 ip0_${input}.y)
  set(INPUT_FILE0_TXT ip0_${input}.txt)

  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${INPUT_FILE0}  ${INPUT_FILE0_TXT}
    COMMAND ${ip_generator} > ${INPUT_FILE0_TXT}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${sqrtlib}
    COMMENT "Generating output files of for testcase")
  
  add_custom_target(gen_input_${input}
    DEPENDS ${INPUT_FILE0}
    COMMENT "Generated output files")

endmacro() 

####################

macro(EXECUTE file input)
  get_filename_component(main_base_name ${file} NAME_WE)
  set(main_base_name_mangled ${main_base_name}_${input})
  set(exe_generator ctest_ref_${input})

  add_executable(${exe_generator}
    ${file}
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:sqrtlib>
    )

  target_compile_options(${exe_generator} PUBLIC
    -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11 
    -DCTEST_INPUT=${input})


  target_link_libraries(${exe_generator} PUBLIC
    dl pthread
    )

  target_include_directories(${exe_generator} PUBLIC
    ${REF_MATHLIB_DIR}
    )

  set(INPUT_FILE0 ip0_${input}.y)

  set(EXE_FILE0 exeadd_${input}.y)
  set(EXE_FILE_TXT exeadd_${input}.txt)

  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${EXE_FILE0} ${EXE_FILE_TXT}
    COMMAND ${exe_generator}  > ${EXE_FILE_TXT}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${INPUT_FILE0} ${sqrtlib}
    COMMENT "Generating output files of for testcase")
  
  add_custom_target(gen_execute_${input}
    DEPENDS ${EXE_FILE0}
    COMMENT "Generated output files")

    # add test to simulate
  add_test(NAME ctest_execute_${input}
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
                               --target gen_execute_${input})

  #add_dependencies(execute_${main_base_name_mangled}   
  #gen_input)

endmacro() 

#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
# add test directories
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#

set(TEST_DIRECTORIES
    step2
   )

foreach(dir ${TEST_DIRECTORIES})
  add_subdirectory(${dir})
endforeach()
```

**step2 folder**

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(UT_IPGEN_FILES tutorial.cpp)
set(UT_EXECUTE_FILES execute.cpp)

set(input_integer_range 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 )

foreach(ip_integer ${input_integer_range})
  GENERATION(${UT_IPGEN_FILES} ${ip_integer})
  EXECUTE(${UT_EXECUTE_FILES} ${ip_integer})
endforeach(ip_integer)
```

Result:
1st Run:

```
      Start  1: ctest_execute_1
      Start  2: ctest_execute_4
      Start  3: ctest_execute_9
      Start  4: ctest_execute_16
      Start  5: ctest_execute_25
      Start  6: ctest_execute_36
      Start  7: ctest_execute_49
      Start  8: ctest_execute_64
 1/12 Test  #4: ctest_execute_16 .................***Failed    1.14 sec
 2/12 Test  #6: ctest_execute_36 .................   Passed    1.27 sec
 3/12 Test  #7: ctest_execute_49 .................   Passed    1.32 sec
 4/12 Test  #8: ctest_execute_64 .................   Passed    1.32 sec
      Start  9: ctest_execute_81
      Start 10: ctest_execute_100
      Start 11: ctest_execute_121
      Start 12: ctest_execute_144
 5/12 Test  #1: ctest_execute_1 ..................   Passed    1.33 sec
 6/12 Test  #2: ctest_execute_4 ..................   Passed    1.33 sec
 7/12 Test  #3: ctest_execute_9 ..................   Passed    1.33 sec
 8/12 Test  #5: ctest_execute_25 .................   Passed    1.33 sec
 9/12 Test #10: ctest_execute_100 ................   Passed    0.54 sec
10/12 Test #11: ctest_execute_121 ................   Passed    0.55 sec
11/12 Test  #9: ctest_execute_81 .................   Passed    0.55 sec
12/12 Test #12: ctest_execute_144 ................   Passed    0.55 sec
92% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 12

Total Test time (real) =   1.88 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      4 - ctest_execute_16 (Failed)
```

2nd Run:

```
      Start  1: ctest_execute_1
      Start  2: ctest_execute_4
      Start  3: ctest_execute_9
      Start  4: ctest_execute_16
      Start  5: ctest_execute_25
      Start  6: ctest_execute_36
      Start  7: ctest_execute_49
      Start  8: ctest_execute_64
 1/12 Test  #6: ctest_execute_36 .................   Passed    1.31 sec
 2/12 Test  #7: ctest_execute_49 .................   Passed    1.36 sec
 3/12 Test  #8: ctest_execute_64 .................   Passed    1.36 sec
      Start  9: ctest_execute_81
      Start 10: ctest_execute_100
      Start 11: ctest_execute_121
 4/12 Test  #1: ctest_execute_1 ..................   Passed    1.37 sec
 5/12 Test  #2: ctest_execute_4 ..................   Passed    1.37 sec
 6/12 Test  #3: ctest_execute_9 ..................   Passed    1.36 sec
 7/12 Test  #4: ctest_execute_16 .................   Passed    1.36 sec
 8/12 Test  #5: ctest_execute_25 .................   Passed    1.37 sec
      Start 12: ctest_execute_144
 9/12 Test #11: ctest_execute_121 ................   Passed    0.50 sec
10/12 Test #10: ctest_execute_100 ................   Passed    0.51 sec
11/12 Test  #9: ctest_execute_81 .................   Passed    0.51 sec
12/12 Test #12: ctest_execute_144 ................   Passed    0.34 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 12

Total Test time (real) =   2.01 sec
```

Comment: Your tests seem to run `make` in the **same directory** (by executing `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target ...`). **Concurrent invocations** of `make` in the same directory are never guarantee to work correctly. E.g. all these invocations are trying to create the same object file `mysqrt.o`, and this creation is definitely not *thread-safe*. By running `make sqrtlib` before `ctest` you may be sure that the object file is already created when tests are run. But you still could get other conflicts in parallel tests.

Comment: Normally, tests are firstly **built**, and only then they are **run**. So, possible workflow would be 1. `cmake <...>`. 2. `make`. 3. `ctest`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, But I am creating the `sqrtlib` only one time as `object_library`. and attaching this library for number of inputs execution.My idea behind was to reduce the execution of `mysqrt` code every time .So created the library.But you are mentioning that :  E.g. all these invocations are trying to create the same object file mysqrt.o  .How is this possible .Is there any changes I need to do to make sure that I will generate sqrtlib only one time and use this library for given input sqrt calculation (except running make sqrt manually before cmake run.)

Comment: @Tsyvarev,  I am running my test this way :  1.  `cmake -G Ninja ../`       2. `ninja test`  .  I am making sure the step2_build doesnot have old binaries and object files . There is **no** `make` command I am executing here .

Comment: `step2_build$ rm -rf * `
`step2_build$ cmake -G Ninja ../`
`step2_build$ ninja test`

Comment: Supporting **concurrent invocations** of a built tool on the **same project** would require using **syncrhonization** mechanisms, which, among other things, negatively affects on a performance. `make` utility doesn't support such concurrent invocations, and `ninja`, probably, too. So, if you want to run `cmake --build` from your tests, you need to make sure that this command won't be run concurrently. But in that case running tests in parallel would have a little advantage against non-parallel run.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, So from your reply and `cmake` documentation about `build_command`, I understood that after invoked, `cmake --build` command line will launch the underlying build system tool which is a `make utility` & `make` wont support concurrent invocations.  But I am not sure then why this `sqrtlib` is executing every time .as it is a library and need to execute only one time and store the lib and attach with the execution during MACRO execution,But why it is also building every time and generating the object file ? as it is outside and added as just `MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${INPUT_FILE0} ${sqrtlib}`

Comment: @Tsyvarev, My understanding about the concurrent behavior of given test case is that, `sqrtlib `happens only one time through out the run .But this concurrent execution is nothing but  `GENERATION` macro executes parallely for given set of inputs `set(input_integer_range 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 ) `

Comment: In a simplified form workflow of `make`: **0.** You ask it to build `ctest_input_1` executable. **1.** `make` finds out, that the executable depends on object `mysqrt.o` **2.** `make` checks wither `mysqrt.o` exists. If exist, goto step 4. **3.**. Run a compiler which would create and write `mysqrt.o`. **4**. As `mysqrt.o` exists, executable can be created now using `mysqrt.o` object. Got it?

Comment: Now assume another, **parallel invocation** of `make` which builds `ctest_input_1`. Assume this invocation performing steps 1 and  2 in **parallel** with the step 3 of the first invocation. Assume that the first invocation has already created `mysqrt.o` file but hasn't fill it yet. So, another invocation will find `mysqrt.o` object already existed, and goes to the step 4. At this step it will attempt to create an executable from the `mysqrt.o` file, but this file is empty! This is exactly what the error message tells you.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, now its totally clear for me. for example **input** `4` and `9` from input `input_integer_range` are executing parallely . as for first time input `4` find that `mysqrt.o` is not available. So creating the object file but by that time (during parallel execution) for input  `9`, it check that `mysqrt.o` object is already available because input `4`  has created that (which is not yet created. its under the process of creation). and for input  `9` it goes for the creation of executable using the `mysqrt.o` and hence getting error.I hope my understanding is correct & thank you so much

Comment: Yes, this is correct interpretation. Depending on timing, there are other possible consequences of parallel `make` invocation too. E.g. these invocations could find (at the same time) that `mysqrt.o` object is not created yet, and both call a compiler for create this same file. In a result, the content of the file could be a mess.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, your comment answered my question. I understood one important point about `cmake --build` command is launching the build system tool which is nothing but the make utility and that can not support the concurrent execution of the test cases. As I do not have enough points to mark as your comments as a answer for this question,But I accepted your comments as the answer for the question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests executing

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target ...
```

which effectively runs `make` (or whatever build tool you use) in the project's build directory.

But **concurrent invocations** of `make` in the same directory are never guarantee to work correctly. This is why you got weird errors when run tests in parallel (with `CTEST_PARALLEL_LEVEL` variable being set).

E.g. all these tests are trying to create the same object file `mysqrt.o`, and this creation is definitely not *thread-safe*.

By running

```
make sqrtlib
```

before

```
ctest
```

you may be sure that the object file is already created when tests are run, and tests wouldn't attempt to create it again.
But you still could get other conflicts in the parallel tests.

---

It depends on what actually you want to check by the testing, but usually a *test* checks **behavior** of some program or library, and it doesn't intend to check a compilation(building) of that program. Because of that, compilation(building) commands are performed **before** the testing.

Usually it is convenient to follow(implement) this workflow for testing:

```
# Configure the project
cmake <source-directory>
# Build the project.
# It builds both program/library intended, and the tests themselves.
make
# run tests
ctest <params>
```

In that case a test could have the following definition:

```
add_test(NAME ctest_execute_${input} COMMAND ${exe_generator})
```

(Unless you want to check output of the test by some automatic way, no need to explicitely save this output by redirecting into the file. `ctest` by itself would collect the output of the test, so you may read it if needed).